# R: Replace loop (with skipped indices) and sapply to speed up performance

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, sapply

How can I replace the `for`-loop below, to speed up the calculations? I thought of using nested `sapply`, but I don't see how I can do this since I only want to loop over every fourth index.

Or would there be even a more efficient way than using apply functions in this set-up?

Also, I am calculating 3 times new values based on the previous calculations using sapply. Any suggestions on how to improve performance in this set-up are welcome.

Here a reproducible similar example of what I am calculating:

```
#Table Creation
Column_Names<-c("LE","exp_0","ces_0","ret_0","int_0","exp_1","ces_1","ret_1","int_1","exp_2","ces_2","ret_2","int_2","exp_3","ces_3","ret_3","int_3","exp_4","ces_4","ret_4","int_4")
entities<-c("E1","E2","E3","E4","E5","E6")

c0<-c("E2","E2","E1","E4","E4","E6")
c1<-runif(6, min=0, max=100)
c2<-runif(6, min=0, max=c1)
c3<-c1-c2
c4<-runif(6,min=0, max=100)

data<-cbind.data.frame(c0,c1,c2,c3,c4)
rownames(data)<-entities
data[,5:length(Column_Names)]<-list(0)
colnames(data)<-Column_Names

#Calculations
for (col_indx in seq(6,length(Column_Names), by=4)) {
  sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x){
    data[x, Column_Names[col_indx]]<<-data[x,Column_Names[col_indx-1]]+data[x,Column_Names[col_indx-2]]
    data[x,Column_Names[col_indx+1]]<<-data[x, Column_Names[col_indx-3]]*data[x,Column_Names[col_indx]]
    })

  sapply(1:nrow(data) , function(x){
    data[x,Column_Names[col_indx+2]]<<-data[x,Column_Names[col_indx]]-data[x,Column_Names[col_indx+1]]
    })
  
  sapply(1:nrow(data) , function(x){
    tmp <- subset(data, rownames(data)[x] == data$LE[x])
    sum_int_ass<-ifelse(nrow(tmp)==0,0,sum(tmp[,Column_Names[col_indx+1]]))
    data[x,Column_Names[col_indx+3]]<<-sum_int_ass}
    ) 
  return(data)
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO.  It would be extremely useful to have a [mcve] ...

Comment: `sapply` accepts an argument which specifies arbitrary set of index values on which to operate.   Try that out, maybe

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I tried it out with replacing the for loop with sapply, but unfortunately it did not make a difference wrt time performance...